# convert html to image in java using SpagoBI url

Tags: java, html, spagobi

```
HtmlImageGenerator htmlImageGenerator=new HtmlImageGenerator();
htmlImageGenerator.loadUrl("url");
htmlImageGenerator.saveAsImage("abc.png");
```

I have a spagoBI url where this image will save and how can i use this image

Comment: How is this question relevant for angularjs?